# SelectRadio onchage event not updating value when page is saved

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a **Salesforce** Visualforce page with a controller along with some html. When clicking on radio buttons I am able to calculate and update a 'Risk Score' but when I save the page the onchange event does not update the RiskScore. If I refresh the page or open it back up then the onchange event updates the RiskScore. Not sure why saving the page causes the onChange event to update the RiskScore displayed. Below is an illustration, controller and Visualforce code that is used. Would appreciate any suggestions on this. Included the constructor as well.

[image]

```
    <apex:tab label="Risk Score" > 
    <apex:outputPanel Style="width:75%;"  layout="block">

    <apex:outputPanel id="out" > 
    <b><apex:outputText style="text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:black" value="Average Risk Score"/></b> &nbsp; &nbsp; 

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(Account_Summary__c.Average_Risk_Score__c=null,false,true)   }"> 
    <div class="numberCircle">
    <apex:outputText value="{0,number}" >
    <apex:param value="{!Account_Summary__c.Average_Risk_Score__c}" />
    </apex:outputText>                             
    </div> 
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <b><apex:outputText style="text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:black" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; <apex:outputText style="text-align:right;font-size:14px;color:blue" value="{!averageTotalRisk}" rendered="{!if(averageTotalRisk=='Select a score fore every risk.','true','false')}" />  </b>           
    </apex:outputPanel> 

    <br></br>
      <table class="htmlRiskTable">
               <tr valign="center">
                  <td> 
                  <apex:outputText style="text-align:right;font-size:12px;color:blue" value="Underwriting Audit Risk Score" title="Seasoned UW department, well managed, good controls, good documentation, good pricing decisions vs. inexperienced staff, lack of management controls, poor documentation, unjustified price cutting"/> 
                  </td>
                  <td> 
                    <apex:selectRadio id="Radio1" value="{!Account_Summary__c.Risk1__c}" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="out" action="{!calculateaverageRisk}"/>                 
                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!AuditItems}"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
    ......
      </table>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:tab>
```

---

```
    //******************************************************************
    public Decimal TotalRisk { get; set; }  //used for risk assessment
    public String averageTotalRisk { get; set; }//store average risk    

//Risk Score
         public List<SelectOption> getAuditItems() {
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('0', 'No Audit in the Last 3 Years'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('0', 'Poor'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('5', 'Average'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('10', 'Superior'));
            return options;
        }

        //calculate the average risk based on the logic
        Public void calculateaverageRisk() {
            if ((AccountSummary.Risk1__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk2__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk3__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk4__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk5__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk6__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk7__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk8__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk9__c == null) || (AccountSummary.Risk10__c == null)) {
                averageTotalRisk = 'Select a score fore every risk.';
            } else {
                TotalRisk = ((integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk1__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk2__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk3__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk4__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk5__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk6__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk7__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk8__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk9__c) + integer.valueof(AccountSummary.Risk10__c)));
                Integer TotalRiskCalc = Integer.valueOf((TotalRisk / 100)*100);
                averageTotalRisk = string.valueof(TotalRiskCalc);            
                this.AccountSummary.Average_Risk_Score__c = Integer.valueOf(averageTotalRisk);
            }
        }

    //******************************************************************
        Public Void SaveMe() {        
            try {
                string selectedSubmissions = selectedOptions (this.SelectedSubmissions);
                this.AccountSummary.SelectedOptions__c = selectedSubmissions;
                stdController.save();            
                getSelectedSubmissions();   //used to fetch all submission options           
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }
        }

//***************************************************

       //Constructors
        public AccountSummaryController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            try {
                this.stdController = controller;
                this.AccountSummary = (Account_Summary__c) controller.getRecord();
                this.ParentAcct = new Account();
                this.IsNew = (this.AccountSummary.Id == null);
                this.hidecols = true; //toggles hidden columns. true=show all hidden columns.
                risk1 = 'null';



       // initialize the variable as an empty list
        types = new List<Account_Summary__c>();
       // initialize contract types to search on
       this.contractprefix = new List<String> { 'AM%', 'TR%', 'AH%', 'AC%', 'CT%' }; 
       // initialize contract status to search
       this.contractstatus = new List<String> { 'Bound', 'Renewed'};    

                if (this.AccountSummary.Report_Status__c == 'Final') {
                    this.statusupdate = true; //toggles report status. true=report status is final.
                } else {
                    this.statusupdate = false;
                }

                //Keep. Aproval process requirement may come back.
                //this.isLocked = Approval.isLocked(this.AccountSummary.Id);  //test is record is locked via approval request.   //causing error Arg 1 cannot be null.
                //this.isLocked = false;
                //System.Debug('RICK TEST');


                if (!this.IsNew) {
                    //Lock record processing
                    this.isLocked = Approval.isLocked(this.AccountSummary.Id);  //test is record is locked via approval request.   //causing error Arg 1 cannot be null.
                    if (this.isLocked) {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'CRE locked. Report Status set to Final. To edit click button "Mark CRE as Draft."'));
                    }
                }

                //Get Url Parameters
                if (this.IsNew) {
                    Map<string, string> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
                    //this.RecordTypeId = params.get(URL_PARAM_RECORD_TYPE_ID);   //only needed for new record
                    this.AccountId = params.get(URL_PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID);          //only needed for new record
                    this.ExternalId = params.get(URL_PARAM_EXTERNAL_ID);        //only needed for new record
                    this.SubmissionYear = params.get(URL_PARAM_SUBMISSION_YEAR);
                    this.Name = params.get(URL_PARAM_SUBMISSION_NAME);
                    //this.ExternalId = ParentAcct.External_ID_BA__c;
                }

                //Get Submission Year   //used to query for financial submission and contract records.
                this.SubmissionYear = this.AccountSummary.Name;


                if (SubmissionYear == null) {
                    SubmissionYear = this.SubmissionYear;  //grabs value passed in thru URL as new record.
                }
                if (SubmissionYear == null) {  // need a year if the url year is null as well.
                    SubmissionYear = string.valueof(system.today().year());
                }
                if (SubmissionYear != null) {
                    this.accountsummary.name = this.SubmissionYear;
                    this.ContractYear = string.valueof((integer.valueof(SubmissionYear) - 1));
                } else {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Invalid Submission Year. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
                }


                //Get Account Id Prefix
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();  // errored when
                this.accountIdPrefix = dsr.getKeyPrefix();

                //Get Account Id
                Id AccountId = this.AccountSummary.Account_Name__c;


                if (AccountId == null) {
                    //string param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
                    string param1 = this.AccountId;  //grabs value passed in thru URL as new record.

                    if (isAccountId(param1)) {
                        AccountId = param1;
                    } else {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Invalid Account Id. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
                    }
                }

                //Get External Account Business Affiliate Id   //used to query acct for submission records.
                ExternalId = this.AccountSummary.AccountExt_ID_BA__c;

                if (ExternalId == null) {
                    ExternalId = this.ExternalId;  //grabs value passed in thru URL as new record.
                    ExternalId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('exid');
                }


                //Load Account Record
                List<Account> accounts = queryAccounts(AccountId);

                if (accounts.isEmpty() == true) {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'No records were found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));
                } else if (accounts.size() > 1) {

                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'More than 1 record found. Please contact the help desk with this error'));

                }

                else {
                    this.ParentAcct = accounts[0];
                    this.AccountSummary.Account_Name__c = this.ParentAcct.Id;
                }

                SelectedSubmissions = new List<String>();

                if (!this.IsNew) {
                    //Get stored selection options when re-opening saved record.
                    this.SubmissionOptions = getSubmissionOptions(this.ExternalId, this.SubmissionYear);    //this is adding 2 bogus submission options
                    this.SelectedSubmissions = toArray(this.AccountSummary.SelectedOptions__c);
                    getSelectedSubmissions();   //used to fetch all submission options
                }

                else {
                    this.SubmissionOptions = getSubmissionOptions(this.ExternalId, this.SubmissionYear);    //this is adding 2 bogus submission options  
                }


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }

        }
```

Comment: When are you calling the `SaveMe()` method?

Comment: SaveMe() is called anytime when the page is created or edited allowing the user to save as they edit the page. Seems to show same behavior for a newly created record or editing an existing record.

Comment: corrected the code. Moved outputPanel id="out" to reflect code being used. Current issue still remains though.